# selenium builder switching windows

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have the selenium builder Firefox plugin. when testing I am having trouble when I click on a link it opens up a window in Firefox that I cannot close and I can't figure out how to switch to that window. I've seen some that use code but I wasn't trying to use code. I'm new to this, help? I have tried the switch window command but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can u update ques with the code that u tried

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a window that jumped out. It could have been a "alert".

You may want to do a bit research on "how to handle alert windows using selenium".
A youtube video may be helpful to you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Hn2bErpwDQ

A bit additional information, for firefox, you can install "firebug" plugin, which will help you find out a lots of information about a window / alert.